# osx: how to manage Services menu, reorder items?

Tags: macos, services, context-menu

The ordering of services in the Services context menu seems totally random. Is there any way to edit it? 
In addition, sometimes added/modified services (that I created) don't show up immediately.

Comment: Isn't it just alphabetically?

Comment: I thought so, and I tried naming services starting with underscore or dash, but they appeared in the middle.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just that these special characters are ignored when sorting? Have you tried e.g. `aaaServiceName`?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just that these special characters are ignored when sorting? Have you tried e.g. `aaaServiceName`?

Comment: Definately. There are things starting with C below those starting with O. There's U above and below O, etc.